# programa en java que eleve 100 numeros al cubo

Tags: java

```
package pow;
import java.util.*;
/**
 *
 * @author Cuenta Casa
 */
public class Pow {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int num;
        do{
           System.out.print("Introduce un numero entero >=0 ");
           num = sc.nextInt();
        }while(num<0);
        System.out.println("3 ^ " + num + " = " + potencia(num));
    }
    public static double potencia(int n){
           if(n==0)   //caso base
              return 1;
           else
              return 3 * potencia(n-1);   
    }

}`introducir
```

el código aquí`

Comment: saludos es la primera ocasión que pido ayuda en estos foros, espero me puedan ayudar. necesito que el programa eleve un numero al cubo y el,resultado al cubo y el resultado al cubo y así sucesivamente. espero me puedan ayudar gracias

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: usa el boton [edit] para agregar toda la informacion necesaria en la pregunta. Los comentarios son solo para eso, para dejar comentarios. Mira los links que te pase. Si esto es un ejercicio, por favor, aclara cual es el programa que tenes especificamente.

Answer (score 1):

Tú puedes usar el método [`pow` de la clase `Math`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#pow(double,%20double)) para calcular cualquier potencia.

Veamos un programa con un método:

```
calcularPotencia(int intValor, int intPotencia)
```

Recibirá dos parámetros, el valor y la potencia que queremos calcular.

Este sería el código:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String strMensaje = "Escriba un número: ";
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            System.out.print(strMensaje);

            while (!input.hasNextInt()) {
                strMensaje = "No escribió un número. Escriba un número: ";
                System.out.print(strMensaje);
                input.next();
            }
            int intValor = input.nextInt();
            if (intValor == 0) {
                strMensaje = "El número debe ser mayor que 0. Escriba un número: ";

                i = i - 1;
            } else {
                strMensaje = "Escriba un número: ";
                calcularPotencia(intValor, 3);
            }
        }
        input.close();

    }

    public static void calcularPotencia(int intValor, int intPotencia) {

        double dblPotencia = Math.pow(intValor, intPotencia);
        System.out.println("Potencia " + intPotencia + " de " + intValor + " es " + dblPotencia);

    }

}
```

---

### Ejemplo del resultado:

```
Escriba un número: 27
Potencia 3 de 27 es 19683.0
Escriba un número: a
No escribió un número. Escriba un número: 90
Potencia 3 de 90 es 729000.0
Escriba un número: 0
El número debe ser mayor que 0. Escriba un número: 43
Potencia 3 de 43 es 79507.0
```

Comment: Gracias amigo A. Cedano en cuanto  a lo de la clase pow si lo entiendo, el detalle es como hacerlo recursivo hasta 100 números, ejemplo que eleve el 3 al cubo y el resultado del cubo de tres lo eleve al cubo y el resultado de este numero lo eleve al cubo y asi.