# ¿Cómo controlar que lo introducido en un Scanner de Java sea un número y sea mayor que cero respetando iteraciones de un bucle?

Tags: java

Respondiendo a [una pregunta aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/113105/29967), tuve que crear un `Scanner` que cumpliese estos requerimientos:

1. Que lo introducido sea numérico. Si no lo es que lo diga y pida un número.
2. Que dicho número sea mayor que `0`. Si no lo es, que  lo diga y pida un número mayor que `0`.
3. Obtener `n` valores para pasarlos luego a un método.

De forma rápida he creado una solución ¿arcaica?:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String strMensaje = "Escriba un número: ";
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            System.out.print(strMensaje);

            while (!input.hasNextInt()) {
                strMensaje = "No escribió un número. Escriba un número: ";
                System.out.print(strMensaje);
                input.next();
            }
            int intValor = input.nextInt();
            if (intValor == 0) {
                strMensaje = "El número debe ser mayor que 0. Escriba un número: ";

                i = i - 1;
            } else {
                strMensaje = "Escriba un número: ";
                calcularPotencia(intValor, 3);
            }
        }
        input.close();

    }

    public static void calcularPotencia(int intValor, int intPotencia) {

        double dblPotencia = Math.pow(intValor, intPotencia);
        System.out.println("Potencia " + intPotencia + " de " + intValor + " es " + dblPotencia);

    }

}
```

La cuestión aquí es que se deben pasar al método **100 valores correctos**, por eso resto `1`  a `i` cuando el valor no es correcto, de lo contrario estaría pasando `n` valores erróneos de menos.

El código funciona, pero me parece poco elegante:

- Restar `1`  a `i`
- La forma de usar los `System.out.print` en el sentido de que tengo que repetir en dos partes del código el mensaje `Escriba un número:`

Me pregunto si hay una forma más elegante de hacerlo.

Comment: Puedes utilizar un `try catch` para confirmar lo de si es un numero, como explico en esta [respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/108103/como-valido-un-dato-en-java/108126#108126). Y para saber si el numero es mayor a uno, con un condicional basta, tal como esta haciendo ahora.

Answer (score 0):

Hay varios puntos en los cuales uno puede hacer más elegante su código.
1. Dado el caso de que no siempre se requiere hacer un i++, en este caso considero más útil usar un while en vez de un for, ya que uno decide cuándo avanzar o no. Esto sería una solución al problema de i = i-1;

2. El manejo de excepciones puede ser muy importante a la hora de evaluar estos casos. Tienes el camino ideal que sería que el que interactue con la consola ingrese siempre números, aunque también pueden ocurrir caminos alternativos (excepciones) como el ingreso de un número negativo o cero, o el ingreso de una cadena que no sea un número. Dicho esto, uno puede aplicar el manejo de excepciones en validaciones que obligan a que todo transcurra por el camino ideal, y si no es el caso, poder mostrar un mensaje de cual es el desvío que ocurrió al momento de ir por dicho camino. Esto además de solucionar la repetición de el "Escriba un número" evita los if else que, generalmente (este caso es chico) se agrandan hasta el punto de que cuesta mantener un código repleto de ifs.

Una solución más elegante podría ser esta.

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int i = 0;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    while (i < 100) {
        System.out.print("Escriba un número: ");

        try {
            validarNumerico(input);

            int valor = input.nextInt();
            validarCero(valor);

            calcularPotencia(valor, 3);

            i++;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }

    }
    input.close();

    System.exit(0);

}

private static void validarCero(int valor) throws Exception {
    if (valor <= 0)
        throw new Exception("Debe ingresar un valor mayor que cero");
}

private static void validarNumerico(Scanner input) throws Exception {
    if (!input.hasNextInt()) {
        input.next();
        throw new Exception("Debe ingresar un valor numérico");
    }
}

public static void calcularPotencia(int intValor, int intPotencia) {

    double dblPotencia = Math.pow(intValor, intPotencia);
    System.out.println("Potencia " + intPotencia + " de " + intValor + " es " + dblPotencia);

}
```

}

A tener en cuenta: 
Al ser un ejemplo usé la clase Exception. Pero siempre es una buena práctica crear nuestras propias clases de excepciones para el manejo correcto del control de las excepciones.